# Correct usage of well-known in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

I was wondering about the adjective well-known's usage in a sentence. How is it used correctly? Can one say/write:

> I am well-known about my sister-in-law's arrival to England to visit me. She's going to stay at my home for 2 weeks.

Comment: No, that usage is incorrect.

Comment: Ok, why is it incorrect? Teach me please :)

Comment: Would it be better to use "informed" instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Well-known" means "known to many people", as in "Stephen Hawking is a well-known scientist."

Comment: Got it, thanks :) The problem was that I translated it directly. "informed" fits  :)